# What is the medullary bulb transition?

Tags: terminology, neurophysiology, neuroanatomy, physiology, neurology

Does "medullary bulb transition" make sense in neuroanatomy internattionally or is it a Brazilian invention and there is no term like that in English? What is then the difference of the "medullary bulb transition" and the "medullo-pontine junction"?

I am trying to translate an MRI report for social security reasons.

It reads:

> Discovered a lesion affecting supra and infratentorial compartments to the right of the midline, measuring about 6,4 x 5,4 x 4,0 cm, showing hyposignal on T1 and heterogeneous signal on T2, with cystic areas and highlight markedly heterogeneous by the contrast, mass effect of which deforms the brainstem and the IV ventricle, contralateraly bypassing there structures and causing an insinuation of the cerebellar tonsils toward the foramen magnum, compressing the medullary bulb transition. It is observed that the basilar artery and a portion of the right vertebral artery intracranial transit are wrapped by the lesion.

https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEA_enGR828GR828&sxsrf=ALeKk026hx-mS3zBxB_mzf3yskD-wp6KyQ%3A1604840622814&ei=ruynX8qfMY7MaOrLvsAH&q=%22Medullary+Bulb+Transition%22&oq=%22Medullary+Bulb+Transition%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIHCCMQrgIQJzoECAAQR1DDKFjCQGD8QWgAcAJ4AIAB3QGIAfkCkgEFMC4xLjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjKrvmZgfPsAhUOJhoKHeqlD3gQ4dUDCA0&uact=5

A google search shows that there are only 5 papers (or even less as some are doubles) in English language with this term from University of São Paulo and some other Spanish speaking Professors.

Just an educated guess.
An exam states

> causing an insinuation of the cerebellar tonsils towards the foramen
> magnum, compressing the medullary bulb transition

How confident would you be that the "medullary bulb transition" is the transition bettween spinal cord (from medula spinalis) and medulla (same times called bulb) inside the foramen magnum (a kind of medullo-bulbar juction)?

Comment: Can you try to provide the motivation behind the question? Is there a specific text you are trying to understand? (in which case that specific context would be helpful) Otherwise, why would you be interested in a term that hardly occurs?

Comment: @BryanKrause I am trying to translate an MRI report for social security reasons. I editted the question and provided the section that poses a problem to me.

Comment: It is interesting that a Google search reveals papers when [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/) does not show 1

Comment: @ChrisRogers Do you have any contributions to make?